# Adding a move/fade transition or effect using CSS/HTML in existing code

Tags: html, css, optimization, css-transitions

I have a method that displays an image, and when clicked, displays a simple caption. The caption simply appears and disappears when tapped. However, it would be more interesting to move/fade the caption with a transition or effect as it appears and disappears.

> **Question**
>
> How can I add a move/fade effect to the caption using CSS/HTML in the
>   existing code?

**Demo**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWYQoG

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-image">
    <input type="checkbox" id="gallery" />
    <label for="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image-icon">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Georges_Seurat_026.jpg/309px-Georges_Seurat_026.jpg" alt=“Gallery." height="240" width="309">
        </div>
     </label>
     <div class="gallery-image-button">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery-image {
}
.gallery-image-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#gallery {
    display:none;
}
#gallery:not(:checked) ~ .gallery-image-button {
    display:none;
}
#gallery:checked ~ .gallery-image-button {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the  transition with some movement

```css
.gallery-image-button {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#gallery:not(:checked)~.gallery-image-button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -30px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#gallery:checked~.gallery-image-button {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-image">
  <input type="checkbox" id="gallery" />
  <label for="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image-icon">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Georges_Seurat_026.jpg/309px-Georges_Seurat_026.jpg" alt=“Gallery." height="240" width="309">
        </div>
     </label>
  <div class="gallery-image-button">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: That's great! Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
#gallery:not(:checked) ~ .gallery-image-button {
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
#gallery:checked ~ .gallery-image-button {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to move it upwards into position as it fades?

Comment: You'll need to use `position` for that (`relative` and `absolute`), please refer to : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thank you for the reference.